# IIS Url Rewrite not working with nested WP installs

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, url-rewriting

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue with my WP install. I have 3 installs of WP on the server, as follows.

- root (Wordpress)

  - /Style (Wordpress)
  - /Classifieds (Wordpress)

The one at the root is working but the others are throwing a 500 error. they did work recently but not sure what happened.

I think it might be the config and rewrite rules?

ROOT - WebConfig

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
            <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                    </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
            </rule></rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

STYLE - WebConfig

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules><rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true"><match url="^index\.php$" ignoreCase="false" /><action type="None" /></rule><rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true"><match url="." ignoreCase="false" /><conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll"><add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" /><add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" /></conditions><action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php" /></rule>
            <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
            </rules>
<Clear/>
    </rewrite>

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

ISS ERROR LOG (IP and Website Url removed for security)

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5 
#Version: 1.0 
#Date: 2013-12-21 17:43:52 
#Fields: date time s-sitename s-computername s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs-version cs(User-Agent) cs(Cookie) cs(Referer) cs-host sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken 
2013-12-21 17:43:52 W3SVC9 AWKS 888.888.888.88 GET / - 443 - 88.888.88.888 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/31.0.1650.63+Safari/537.36 Comm100_CC_Identity_180737=-59;+comm100_session_180737=-73 - www.website.com 301 0 0 437 439 343
```

Comment: Do you see anything in the log file(s)?

Comment: Added log error to question.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. In case anyone else is having issues with nested WP installs, here is what I did.

ROOTDIRECTORY - WEBCONFIG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(SUBDIRECTORY1|SUBDIRECTORY2)" negate="true" />
                        </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

SUBDIRECTORY 1 & 2 - WEBCONFIG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
        <rule name="SubSite Rule" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```