# Configure Laravel as Subdirectory of Wordpress on IIS

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, laravel-5, url-rewriting

For reasons outside of my control, I need to get a Laravel instance running as a subdirectory of WordPress inside IIS 10. I've tried every conceivable option inside my web.config `<system.webServer><rewrite><rules />` configuration, but I can only ever get one or the other working. If I leave the rewrite rule in for WordPress, Laravel doesn't work (WordPress responds with a 404) and if I disable the WordPress rule, Laravel works but obviously WordPress does not.

Here is the config at the root of the site (where WordPress sits):

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>           
        <rule name="WordPress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
            <match url="*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />

                <!-- Laravel App -->
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/laravel" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Thanks to an SO search, I came across this ([IIS Url Rewrite not working with nested WP installs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721707/iis-url-rewrite-not-working-with-nested-wp-installs)) which had me put a nested web.config inside the subfolder for the Laravel app with the following:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="/(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public/index.php/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Oddly enough, with these it *almost* works - as long as I go to site.com/laravel/public, all the associated views work and everything plays nicely together. I just can't seem to get the /public off of the URL, which obviously isn't usable.

Any tips? I'm certain it's close but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Got it!** I'm still new to Laravel so this didn't dawn on me sooner, but I had a couple of issues. My root `web.config` file was setup correctly, however the nested `web.config` needed to have a `match url="*"` on it, like so:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                   <match url="*" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public/index.php/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
        </rules>
```

Once that was done, they were both working, however without including `/public` on the URL, I was getting a 404 error - Laravel's 404, specifically which means it's working and just doesn't know what I'm requesting. As a total guess, I looked at my routes and added the subdirectory in front of them and suddenly they all work! Example:

```
Route::get('/laravel/entities', 'EntitiesController@index');
```

I don't particularly like having to add the root into all of the routes; however, ours is a very unique situation so the fact that these two can even play nicely with each other is kind of impressive.

Comment: For me, the vital rule was `<clear />` - with that, the default `web.config` that ships with Laravel works just fine.